# SQL exporting data to a file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to setup a job to export data to a file.
The query for this is also in the job.
It produces a temporary table called "temp_tickets".

That works.

Now I want to write the data to a file.
I have this line for that:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp esi_db.dbo.temp_tickets out D:\Websites\enn-portal\temp\esitdata.csv -f D:\Websites\enn-portal\XML\esittickets.xml -T'
```

The file is created, but is remains empty.

I have also tried it without the format file, but same result.

What is going wrong?

I have used this method on an other job and it works there, so why not here?

rg.
Eric

Comment: since you are talking about a temporary table, is it a persistent one as shown in your srcipt `temp_tickets`, a Local Temp Table `#temp_tickets` or a Global Temp Table `##temp_tickets`

Comment: It is a real table in the list, I just drop it when not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the error by executing the bcp line in a regular query window instead of in the sql server agent step.

It provided me with some error data that helped me solve the problem (the format file was not right).